# How do you make a List of Arrays of Colours? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, colors

I need a list of arrays of colours that I can access. So far, I have this:

`public List<Color[,,]> coloursList = new List<Color[,,]>();`

and then, when I want to add to the list,

`Color[,,] testColor = new Color[originalColour, originalColour, originalColour];`

`coloursList.Add(testColor);`

This makes sense to me and it's what others recommended online. The problem is I get three errors at the second line: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Color' to 'int'*.
I don't get why it's looking for int type variables. Any obvious mistakes I may be making?

Comment: Pretty obvious: [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) and [single-dimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: What are you trying to do? coloursList as declared is a list of tridimensional arrays of colors. But I guess what you really want is a list of objects that has three color properties

Comment: List<Color> coloursList = new List<Color>();
            Color newColor = Color.Lime;
            coloursList.Add(newColor);

Comment: @JesúsLópez No, I have a couple of gameobjects that change colour, `newColour = (firstColour + secondColour + thirdColour) / 3;` like that. And I need to save those firstColour, secondColour and ThirdColour somewhere, for each gameobject

Comment: @itsnotandreea_ You can save those colors in an object with three color properties like this: https://gist.github.com/jesuslpm/c15d8f0b1e698f5ebd2b01b2d7a6bd34. I think you are confusing dimensions and indexes

Comment: @JesúsLópez you were right, I was a bit confused about dimensions and indexes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve  this code in C# different ways have look at below code.

```
var Arraylist = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua };
List<Color[]> color = new List<Color[]>();
color.Add(Arraylist);


List<Color[]> colors = new List<Color[]>()
{
    new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua }
};

ArrayList Arraylistcolors = new ArrayList()
{
    new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
Color[,,] testColor = new Color[originalColour, originalColour, originalColour];
```

Doesn't "fill" the array with the values `originalColour, originalColour, originalColour`, but instead it (wrongly, hence the error you receive) declares a multi dimensional array with dimension lengths.

So for example:

```
Color[, ,] array1 = new Color[4, 2, 3];
```

This initializes a 3 dimensional array, with the following lengths

- x dimension has a length of 4
- y dimension has a length of 2
- z dimension has a length of 3

And because `[4, 2, 3]` declares the length of each dimension, you are receiving the mentioned error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Color' to 'int'.

But you don't want a multi dimensional array, you want a simple array (1 dimension) with 3 values, so your array declaration needs to look like this

```
Color[] array1 = new Color[3];
```

Which initializes an empty array with the length of 3.

To fill the array, you could write this:

```
Color[] array1 = new Color[3];
array1[0] = originalColour;
array1[1] = originalColour;
array1[2] = originalColour;
```

If you want to initialize and fill the array in one line the correct syntax is

```
Color[] array1 = new Color[3] { originalColour, originalColour, originalColour };
```

You can shorten the code to this

```
Color[] array1 = new [] { originalColour, originalColour, originalColour };
```

Since you are filling the array with `{ originalColour, originalColour, originalColour }` the compiler knows that you want a 1 dimensional array with a length of 3, so you can only write `new []`.

This array than can be added to a `List<Color[]>` eg.

```
public List<Color[]> coloursList = new List<Color[]>();

Color[] array1 = new [] { originalColour, originalColour, originalColour };
coloursList.Add(array1);
```